# Plot Projects - TTL of notification cache on devices

Tags: android, ios, notifications, geofencing

I'm using Plot Projects service to send geofencing notifications to users of iOS and Android application.

The change that will be made in the system will require some of the notifications to apply to new or different segments. The changes to the notifications (adding and/or changing segments) will be done using the API.

I know there is a cache that holds the notification information on the devices for some time. In this specific case (altering segments), what is the expected wait time before the notification updates are propagated to the devices? Is there a difference between iOS and Android applications?

Asking this because depending on the wait time, the approach on how to communicate this to users and at which time to activate the new notifications might change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When making changes to segments of notifications in the dashboard or through the api it may take a couple of hours before these changes are synced to the devices. Especially for devices that stay for a long time at the same place it may take a longer time.

It is hard to give an exact estimate, since it depends on multiple factors, such as whether the app is actively used by the user or whether the device is moving.